# Syncing IntelliJ projects between different computers

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I work on multiple projects from 3 different computers all using IntelliJ. I want the projects to be synced on all platforms.
How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you use Git?

Comment: You can use any VCS to keep both source and project settings files in sync.

Comment: That's why I'm here, because I have no idea :)

Comment: How do I import the project?

Comment: First choose VCS which you like then use appropriate JetBrains documentation like this for Git https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/using-git-integration.html

Comment: I looked at that help page, but it doesn't say anything about keeping IntelliJ project settings in source control - just keeping the source code in source control. All of our company's repositories have .idea ignored, as it should be - is there a special way to use git to keep project settings up to date?

Answer (score 6):

Appart from VCS mentioned in other answers/comments - this is of course must-have - try for example [gitHub](https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/)..

**I use [syncThing](https://syncthing.net/)**, which has a benefit (drawback for somebody), that it does not use any cloud stora-ge (it uses p2p), which is a benefit for me, because I can sync very quickly on home network without any middleman. It also works through the internet (but you are limited by the bandwidth of course). It has lot of features, including include/exclude rules (there need to be some exclusions to omit some intelliJ config related specific environment or the .git folder).

This way I can sync even some work-in-progress which I dont want to commit yet, or some config files ignored by VCS.

Answer (score 4):

if you are not using a VCS ([Version Control System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control)), it's time you started. The most reasonable one to use at this time is [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)), which is free.

To sync between computers for an intellij project, you can add the `.idea` project directory, the `*.ipr` files (if project files are stored in files, rather than directory) and the `*.iml` files in your project to the VCS, and share it amongst all the computers.